# longestSubstring python solution what does it mean --> for t in s.split(c)

Tags: python, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I have been studying leetCode and I ran into this problem: Given a string s and an integer k, return the length of the longest substring of s such that the frequency of each character in this substring is greater than or equal to k.

The most elegant solution so far is below but I don't understand

A:  What is it trying to do

```
for t in s.split(c)
```

First marching through a set version of string

Then, taking the original `s` (NON-set, or list `s` with duplicates), splitting `s` where the character whose frequency is less than `k`? Then taking one substring at a time? so if `s="aabaaaacdmmmmmm"`, `k=2`

We split on `"b"` first then evaluate aa then split on `"c"` and get `aabaaaa` not sure what we are getting the max of

```py
def longestSubstring(s, k):
    for c in set(s):
        if s.count(c) < k:
            return max(longestSubstring(t, k) for t in s.split(c))
    return len(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `c == 'b'`, `s.split(c)` splits the input into

```
['aa', 'aaaacdmmmmmm']
```

It then calls itself recursively to get the length of the longest substring in each of these.

`longestSubstring('aa', 2)` will return `2` because none of the characters have frequency less than 2.

`longestSubstring('aaaacdmmmmmm', 2)` will do some more recursion, eventually returning `6` because that's the length of `mmmmmm`.

`max(2, 6)` returns `6`, which is returned by the function.

Comment: Thanks it i snow very clear, so basically t is each substring before and after the split

Comment: Right. Note that when `k > 2` it can split into more than 2 substrings.

Comment: one other question @Barmar why is he return len(s)   isn't len(s) the total original length of string?  I think i just figured it out IF there is no character which its len < k return length of original string

Comment: Exactly. That's the base case of the recursion, which is used for `longestSubstring('aa', 2)`